# Transfer UV data from one mesh to another .blend

Tags: uv, workflow, blend-files, linked-data

I want to copy a mesh's UV data (including 3 UV channels) to the same mesh but in another .blend.

Both meshes are identical in vertex count.

Is there a quick solution?

Comment: Append the object in your scene, select the one you want to give the UV to, shift copy the one that you want to copy, Ctrl L > Copy UV Maps?

Comment: Would that add external unwanted data from the appended mesh in the scene ?
As the .blend file is precisely controlled in term of data at exportation, i want to make sure there's no unwanted files in it

Comment: I've just tested and it works fine, give it a try, make sure that you save a copy of your blend somewhere if you don't want to make some mistakes

Comment: I'll try that, thank you, you saved an entire day worth of repetitive work !

Comment: ok you'll tell me if it works

Comment: It worked ! Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

Append the object in your scene, select the one you want to give the UV to, shift copy the one that you want to copy and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> *(Link/Transfer Data)* > *Copy UV Maps*.